# Is there some delay for javascript when executing a function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, delay, google-chrome-app

I am experimenting with creating a chrome extension, and I am running into a very strange problem when my javascript is executing. Some of the code seams to be running on a delay.

Here is the code:

```
var windowArr = new Array();

function create(t) //t = tab to create new window with
{
    newWindow = new Object();
    newWindow.tabId = t.id;
    chrome.windows.create(newWindow, function(w){windowArr.push(w.id);}); //w = new window

    // Here is where it gets weird
    alert(windowArr[0]);// returns "undefined"
    alert(windowArr[0]);// returns "573" // the correct value
}
```

The delay is messing up other parts of my code.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chrome.windows.create` is asynchrounous.

So you should insert it inside the callback, or in another function called inside it.

The second alert works because while you dismiss the first alert box, the window has been created. (and the array is filled)

here an example:

```
chrome.windows.create(newWindow, function(w){
    windowArr.push(w.id);
    step2();
});

function step2() {
    alert(windowArr[0]);
}
```

Comment: My program is actually running through a loop of multiple tabs. So Ideally I would want to pause my program until the new window has been created and its callback function has been called. Do you know if there is any build in function or way to do this, or should I just add something like a 10 millisecond delay after I call chrome.windows.create?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your function callback and your `alert` are run asynchronously. If you want to see the values, put the alert statements inside your function callback:

```
function create(t) //t = tab to create new window with
{
    newWindow = new Object();
    newWindow.tabId = t.id;
    chrome.windows.create(newWindow, function(w){
        windowArr.push(w.id);
        alert(windowArr[0]);
        alert(windowArr[0]);
    });
}
```

Or, if you want to assign these values to a local variable, you can do something like this:

```
function create(t) //t = tab to create new window with
{
    newWindow = new Object();
    newWindow.tabId = t.id;
    var myArray = [];
    chrome.windows.create(newWindow, function(w){
        myArray.push(w.id);
    });

    alert(myArray[0]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Window creation is asynchronous. `chrome.windows.create` schedules the creation and returns immediately, it doesn't wait for the window to be created. While the UI is paused in the first `alert()`, the window runs the completion function, which pushes onto the array. So when the second `alert` runs, it shows the value.